# ffmpeg forward hls stream

Tags: ffmpeg, stream, rtsp, http-live-streaming

I am trying to forward HLS stream to server via RTSP. On the server, it will be transcoded to the multiple bitrate streams so a wide range of users can watch stream.

To achieve this, I am using ffmpeg.

1. Should I stream to my server in best quality because my server will do transcoding to lower bitrate streams?
2. I am using this command:

   > ffmpeg -i http://vevoplaylist-live.hls.adaptive.level3.net/vevo/ch1/appleman.m3u8 -c:v libx264 -preset veryfast -maxrate 2000k -bufsize 2000k -g 60 -c:a aac -b:a 96k -ac 2 -ar 44100 -f rtsp -muxdelay 0.1 rtsp://username:password@95.138.139.123:1935/live/myStream

But my stream is pixelated on some moments like on the picture:
[image: Pixelated stream]
How can I fix that?

3. Is there some better method to achieve this?

Here is log file from ffmpeg.
[Log file](http://geminisoftware.webs.com/ffmpeg-20160703-221647.log)

Comment: That output looks like you're actually losing data somewhere.  It's not a codec issue.

Comment: What can cause data loosing? Do you have an idea how to troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: You'd see it in your FFmpeg logs if it were on the source end, but you didn't post your logs so I don't really know what to tell you.  Plus, you're streaming to another server at that point, and who knows what happens there.  You'll need to split the stream and have FFmpeg dump it locally to determine if it's on the input end or somewhere beyond.

Comment: I updated my original post with log file. I tried to dump stream to mp4 file by changing command output to output.mp4. The file is playing good and smooth like I want.

Comment: Hmmm, strange.  You might have hit a genuine bug then.